# Looking for documentation on process.stdin.on in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm refreshing my memory on JavaScript (wow things have changed in the last couple of years) and learning node. Step one for me in learning anything is to acquaint myself with the docs. I found [nodejs.org/api as a great documentation source for node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/).

So I'm trying to understand how process.stdin.on works. [I found the process.stdin documentation here on nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin), and stdin.on is listed as an example, so I can kind of infer how it works:

```
process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  process.stdout.write('end');
});
```

But I can't find any specific documentation on the on method for stdin. Does anyone know where that documentation can be found? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link is on the first line of the stdin doc.

Comment: JJJ you mean the link for <Stream>? I had combed through that without finding something specific for on... It's kind of the same story, it's referred to in the example code so I can infer what to do, but I don't see any explicit documentation.

Comment: On the third paragraph of the Stream doc, "All streams are instances of EventEmitter." <-- the word "EventEmitter" links to the base class that implements `.on`.

Comment: JJJ Thaaaaaaaank you :D

Comment: Had the exact same question as someone also learning Node and this post helped me find the answer. Thanks @Dribbler for posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for whoever may come across this question also learning node. The "on" method is in the [EventEmitter class, with documentation found here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) as JJJ pointed out in the comments. NodeJS is quite beautiful, but wading through nodejs.org/api can be challenging as a beginner.